# Import module red underlined but code works fine

Tags: python-3.x

I imported 'A.py' in the current module ('B.py'), they are in the same folder. When I run 'B.py', the code works fine. But 'A' in the following line of code is red-underlined -- seems like the system cannot detect the existence of it. Why is this happening?

```
import A
```

Comment: What code editor are you using?

Comment: I think pycharm.